# Add y-axis label to ridgeline plot with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, ridgeline-plot

I want to add a y-axis label to a density ridgeline plot using seaborn in python. To make the ridgeline plot, I am following the code from [the seaborn gallery](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html). For convenience, I have copied their code snippet below. How should I modify this to label the y-axis in a manner that does not overlap the density curves?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
```

To be clear, I'd like the plot to look something like:
[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 2):

You can add the general label like a text use the follow code line `g.fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Y axis label', va='center', rotation='vertical')` and you will obtain the follow:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think replacing `g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)` with `g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.1)` should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, I mean a title for the y-axis, rather than labelling the levels of the y-axis.